# Run a function only in production enviroment in sails js(node js framework)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a model `Transactions` in which I have made a `beforeCreate` method like this:

```
beforeCreate(values,cb){
   //I want this code to be run in just production enviroment, not in devlopement env
   EmailService.sendMail(values.email,values.data);
   cb();
}
```

Here I have made an Service `EmailService` which will send mail to the user. But I do want this to active only in `production enviroment`, not in developement enviroment.

And I do not want to comment this line, because I have lot of other events  which should only be triggered in production enviroment, not in testing enviroment. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application code, you can [access the environment through the global config](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration#?accessing-sailsconfig-in-your-app), like this: `sails.config.environment`.

```
beforeCreate(values,cb){
   // Production
   if (sails.config.environment === "production") {
       EmailService.sendMail(values.email,values.data);
   }
   cb();
}
```

Your Sails.js application runs in the development environment by default. You can run it in production mode by [setting the NODE_ENV environment variable](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration#?environmentspecific-files-config-env) (`NODE_ENV=production node app.js`) or by running [`sails lift --prod`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-lift).

If you wish, you can also choose to set the environment in `config/local.js` instead:

```
module.exports = {
  /***************************************************************************
   * The runtime "environment" of your Sails app is either typically         *
   * 'development' or 'production'.                                          *
   *                                                                         *
   * In development, your Sails app will go out of its way to help you       *
   * (for instance you will receive more descriptive error and               *
   * debugging output)                                                       *
   *                                                                         *
   * In production, Sails configures itself (and its dependencies) to        *
   * optimize performance. You should always put your app in production mode *
   * before you deploy it to a server.  This helps ensure that your Sails    *
   * app remains stable, performant, and scalable.                           *
   *                                                                         *
   * By default, Sails sets its environment using the `NODE_ENV` environment *
   * variable.  If NODE_ENV is not set, Sails will run in the                *
   * 'development' environment.                                              *
   ***************************************************************************/

   // environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
   environment: 'production'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
beforeCreate(values,cb){
   //I want this code to be run in just production enviroment, not in devlopement env
   if (sails.config.environment === 'production') {
     EmailService.sendMail(values.email,values.data);
   }
   cb();
}
```

Comment: will it work when I am not using sails lift, I am using node app.js?

Comment: you will need to set NODE_ENV environment variable to 'production' on your production server. then use node app.js to run your sails app. sails lift is not ment for production use anyway.
to test it localy you can run your app: NODE_ENV=production node app.js